# Fab button with an icon showing shadow in ics (Android 4.1)

Tags: android, android-layout, floating-action-button, android-layout-editor

I have created this layout it works fine on Android 6.0 but in android 4.1 I am getting this weird shadow (black shadows around fab button in the picture).Following is my layout.

Following is the screen [image]

below xml code

```
   <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_avatar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
           <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview_account_profile"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/avatar_a2a"
            app:civ_border_color="@color/material_white"
            app:civ_border_width="2dp" />
           <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_call"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/imageview_account_profile"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageview_account_profile"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton" />
    </RelativeLayout>`
```

Comment: post your `xml` code here

Comment: set background null of imageview.

Comment: @AbdulKawee XML updated

Comment: @HemantParmar you mean to change the background of circular image  view to null ? but what's that to do with fab shadow ?

Comment: instead of src try to set android:background="@drawable/avatar_a2a"

Comment: i think this in 9 patch image, make it background transparent.

Comment: @HemantParmar I tried it didn't work

Comment: @HemantParmar I found the solution thanks for your help

Comment: @ChinthakaDevinda welcome!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add in  `app:elevation="0dp"` to the  `FloatingActionButton`  solved my issue